# show that $x^r_+$ is continuously differentiable if r>1

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need a more rigorous solution to this problem. It states:

Show that $x^r_+$ is continuously differentiable if r>1

I have f=$x^r_+$. Then f'=r$x^{r-1}_+$. r is constant so continuously differentiable on domain. Similarly $x^r_+$ is continuously differentiable if r is rational number greater than one. This seems too straightforward to me. There must be some way to prove this using definitions.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What is the subscript plus sign for.... the positive part?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to define $x^r$ for $r$ not a rational is to define it in terms of limits. Similarly, just using the original definitions it is non-trivial to prove $rx^{r-1}$ is the derivative of $x^r$ if $r$ is a positive real number. It should be a bit easier to argue that $rx^{r-1}$ is continuous for real $r > 1$ and $x > 0$.

Comment: Although they're basically equivalent, I feel it is better to define $x^r$ for non-rational numbers $r$ is using supremums and infimums.